# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when my view controller tries to access a singleton variable a second time

Tags: iphone, singleton, exc-bad-access

I have an app i building which is a simple naviagtion app. I do not want to load the data from my xml multiple times so I am using a singleton to load and hold the data. My first table pushes the view of the second table. This table calls the singleton and the get the array of data from there to display in the table.

This all works fine, I click on a cell in the first table which takes me to the second table where the singleton is used. I navigate back to the the first table, then back to the second table, this is when i get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. It doesn't error when i init the singleton but when I try and access the array in it. The code is as follows

> MediaData *dataClass = [MediaData sharedManager];
>
> //when i check in the singleton the second time sharedManager is already there
>
> sortedData = dataClass.arrMediaData; //this line errors the second time
>
> NSLog(@"sorted array. %@", sortedData);
>
> [dataClass release];

Any help would be great as it is not a very descriptive error, thanks

Comment: You don't have any code that is releasing the dataClass anywhere do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line in your code is causing the issue. Singletons shouldn't be released.

Comment: I didn't have it there originally and had the error, added it because i thought that might help. Just removed it and still get the same error.

Comment: If it's fully implemented as a singleton, any calls to release should just be ignored by the instance

Comment: @Claus, correct. @padatronic, if that's the case, you're not managing the MediaData singleton's memory properly. Look up on implementing Singletons properly, as Claus suggests.

Comment: Right chaps thanks for the help, seem to have fixed it. I am autoreleaseing my objects and this seems to have fixed it. not completely sure what was happening, have a feeling I will understand it properly soon

Answer (score 1):

As Jasarien said, don't release the singleton.

You can use NSZombieEnabled and run on a device to get more descriptive errors: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled